# Add a multiindex level Dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following sample dataframe:

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3,-1),
                                        index=(0,1,2),
                                        columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 'Salad'),('B','Burger')]))
```

[image]

I would like to put the column ('A','Salad') in another dataframe which might be empty or has this column already.

This is the case the df_output is empty or the column already exists in df_b.

```
df_output = pd.concat([df_output, df_temp], axis=1)
```

[image]

In case the column already exists, it just replaces it. However, in case df_output is empty, converts the multilevel index to a single line which is sth I don't want.

This is the case which df_output already has a column:

[image]

And how it should look like after the addition:

[image]

I am trying to use `concat` but the multiindex level of the columns is disappearing.

Comment: Could you show us the input data(dataframe) and the desired output please?

Comment: Can you also provide the other dataframe?

Comment: What is your pandas version? Because if test `df_output = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(), df_temp], axis=1)` it not lost Mulitindex in pandas 0.25.0

Comment: It is only lost if `df_output = pd.concat([df_output, df_temp], axis=1)` and `df_output` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it with the following solution, although I believe it can be done better:

```
if len(df_output.columns):
    df_output = pd.concat([df_output, df_temp], axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
else:
    df_output = df_temp
```